# Play one video in list view

Tags: android

I have a listview with custom adapter and this adapter has a video view. Currently when the adapter is inflated two(or more) videos are played at same time but I want to play only one video(video only in first cell in adapter) and other(s) is(are) in paused state. When we scroll the list the currently played video goes in pause state and video in new visible cell start playing.

**Code:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        MyVideoView view = (MyVideoView) convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new MyVideoView(activity);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.videoView = view;
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        VideoBean aVideo = feeds.get(position);
        holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(aVideo.getVideoUrl());
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: please post the code of your custom adapter

Comment: try this link https://github.com/sanurag51/https-github.com-danylovolokh-VideoPlayerManager